# Getting undefined when trying to read vuex state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Following a simple example in VueMaster course and can't seem to read state from the store. Here's my main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import upperFirst from 'lodash/upperFirst'
import camelCase from 'lodash/camelCase'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

And here's my index.js in the /store folder:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user: { id: 'abc123', name: 'Adam Jahr' },
  },
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {}
})
```

Then, I try and read the state object from a component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Create an Event, {{ $store.state.user.name }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

I don't see anything in the browser for the component. Console shows an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".

Any idea why this very simple example doesn't work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't your import look like this:

```
import store from './store/index'
```

since that is where you are creating your store, check the folder structure, maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Yes, it does work with /index. Thanks so much. I can't explain why it doesn't work with just './store' however (see my comment above), especially when vankatesh shows that it does work in his sandbox. It's a minor thing and I'll move forward, but it kind of shakes my confidence with something simple like this doesn't work.

Comment: I found it strange that it didn't work after seeing his sandbox, but since code was clean and simple that was the only option for mistake. Don't be discouraged, in the future check if everything is imported correctly if nothing is displayed as an error. Keep up the work and please accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see any problem with your code, it's working as expected.

Here is sandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-poitras-sosvs?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Yes, I can see that it is working in your sandbox. Thanks so much for putting that together. But is strange it only works on my side if do "import store from './store/index'" in main.js. If I don't specify /index, it fails. I thought index.js in a folder was automatically picked up, like with the index.js in the router folder, which works without specifically indicating /index.

Comment: you are right, index.js default file for every folder. `import store from './store'` should support to work.

Comment: Agreed. Just not sure why it doesn't in this case. Maybe a typo in my store/index.js?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the store in your component
Something in computed like
return this.$store.state.user

Comment: I've tried adding computed: {  ...mapState(['user'])  }, and accessing user.name and still the same error. "User is undefined". Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: did you check sandbox link -  https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-poitras-sosvs?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Yes. See my comment on your answer.